# when a link is clicked how to select and deselect a checkbox

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have the following checkbox,that when its clicked it passes a name as follows

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2pzpm7qg/)

the checkbox works fine, what i want to achieve is that when the user clicks on the NAME its self the checkbox should get selected and if he clicks it again it should get unselected.
I am not sure how to go about this,currently as shown above you can click on the checkbox and it changes to blue when you deselect it,it goes back to the orignal state,how can i achieve this by clicking on the name?

code

```js
var c = $('<span><a class="internal_link" data-destination="' + this.Destination + '" data-id="' + this.Id + '"><span><input type="checkbox" class="multiselect-markets hidden" id="cb' + this.Id + '"><label for="cb' + this.Id + '" class="checkmark"></label></span></a></span>');
$.each(this.Markets, function() {

  b = $('<li  style="padding-left:28px"> <span style="color:#5a5959;">' + this.MarketName + '</span></li> ');
  b.append(c);
  list.append(b);
});

function test() {
  if ($(this.MarketName).click) {
    // im not sure in here how to tell it if the Name is clicked it should activate the checkbox and if its un clicked it should deselect the checkbox
  }
}
```

```css
.checkmark {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 22px;
  /*height: 22px;*/
  height: 17px;
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
}

.checkmark:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 3px;
  height: 9px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  left: 11px;
  top: 6px;
}

.checkmark {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.checkmark:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 3px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  left: 8px;
  top: 12px;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked+.checkmark:before,
input[type="checkbox"]:checked+.checkmark:after {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>NAME</span>
<span><a class="internal_market_link" data-destination="' + this.Destination + '" data-id="' + this.Id + '"><span><input type="checkbox" class="multiselect-markets" style="display:none;" id="cb' + this.Id + '"><label for="cb' + this.Id + '" class="checkmark"></label></span></a>
</span>
```

your guidance will be highly appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting "checked" for a checkbox with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/setting-checked-for-a-checkbox-with-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your `<span>NAME</span>` to `<label for="cb' + this.Id + '">NAME</label>`

```css
.checkmark {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 22px;
    /*height: 22px;*/
    height:17px;
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    margin-left:10%;
    margin-bottom:1px;
}
.checkmark:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 3px;
    height: 9px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    left: 11px;
    top: 6px;
}

.checkmark {
    cursor: pointer;
}

 .checkmark:after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        width: 3px;
        height: 3px;
        background-color: #ccc;
        left: 8px;
        top: 12px;
    }

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .checkmark:before,
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .checkmark:after {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<label for="cb' + this.Id + '">NAME</label>
<span><a class="internal_market_link" data-destination="' + this.Destination + '" data-id="' + this.Id + '"><span><input type="checkbox" class="multiselect-markets" style="display:none;" id="cb' + this.Id + '"><label for="cb' + this.Id + '" class="checkmark"></label></span></a></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

wrap it with label instead of span

```
 <label>NAME
 <span><a class="internal_market_link" data-destination="' + 
 this.Destination + '" data-id="' + this.Id + '"><span><input 
 type="checkbox" class="multiselect-markets" style="display:none;" 
 id="cb' + this.Id + '"><label for="cb' + this.Id + '" 
 class="checkmark"></label></span></a></span>
 </label>
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2pzpm7qg/1/)